# Converting between int, float, double, long and string

Tags: c#

I'm making a game where I read some data from json databases. All databases contain similar data, though differ in small ways. Some store "power" as a string, while others store it as a number. There is also one that stores it either as a string or as a number, since sometimes "power" can be "1+X" or something. Also, some store the "power" variable under the name "power" while others use "pwr". So I'm writing a method to easily get these. In my app (written in c#) I get a Dictionary with all the info. So I currently have this:

```
void TryGetValueFromJson<T>(ref T variableToFill, string[] possibleValueNames, Dictionary<string,object> info) {
    foreach (string valueName in possibleValueNames) {
        object value;
        if (info.TryGetValue(valueName, out value)) {
            //I'm stuck here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The variableToFill is, as the name suggest, the variable in my class that I'm reading the value for. a string[] are all possible names for this variable in the different databases ("power", "pwr"). The "info" variable is the json I get from the server.

So now I have to convert different values to the wanted type. If my variableToFill is a string, but the database has it as an int, it should be converted. Though I'm not sure how to do this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is your friend. It's one of those methods that do a lot of dirty work for you, and can save you a ton of code. It relies on a type implementing the `IConvertible` interface, but luckily, most primitive types do:

```
void TryGetValueFromJson<T>(ref T variableToFill, string[] possibleValueNames, Dictionary<string,object> info) 
{
    Type outputType = typeof(T);
    foreach (string valueName in possibleValueNames) 
    {
        object value;
        if (info.TryGetValue(valueName, out value)) 
        {
            variableToFill = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, outputType);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now also wondering, is there a way to change the method to return the value, instead of assigning it to a ref parameter? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Just set the return type to `T` instead of `void`, and `return` the result of `ChangeType`, cast to a T, of course.

Comment: But then I still need the "ref T variableToFill" parameter, right? And if I change that to a "Type" parameter, then C# won't have a way to know what T should be :s

Comment: No, the <T> in the method name does that for you. You can just drop the ref parameter altogether.

Comment: Ah yes! Then I have to call it as TryGetValueFromJson<string>(...), while with the ref I could just do TryGetValueFromJson(name, ...) and it would know the T should be a string without the "<string>". I didn't think if that at first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing, now it complains not all code paths return a value. Though when I add "return new T()" after the loop, it says I can't since T hasn't got the "new" constraint. Then when I add "where T: new()" it won't work with strings since it doesn't seem to have a parameterless constructor. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Use `default(T)` as a catch-all.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use the `Convert` class here:

```
variableToFill = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```